# Why does my TCP connection lock up over OpenVPN?

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, tcp

## Problem

I'm transferring a file that's from 1Mb to 100Mb over a TCP connection from Android 4.4.4 client to a server using java.net.socket and javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket. Without OpenVPN it works as expected, but with it java.net.socket TCP connection locks up every time at the end while javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket locks up sometimes.
My current solution to this problem is to change the "buffer size" to 10 bytes (see code) on client side.
I already tried changing the MTU, MSSFIX and FRAGMENT values in OpenVPN configuration file.

## Set Up

I've made a local network with a WiFi compatible router. Router is not connected to the internet. My Android client is connect via WiFi. I have an eth connection to my computer on which I'm running my java server and Xubuntu on virtualbox with openvpn. Virtualbox is connected with a bridge adapter. Android client can connect to openvpn server and can ping other clients on the network. The current MTU on all machines is 1500 (default).

## Goal

I'm benchmarking the time impact of OpenVPN on plain text and secure socket connections.

## Questions

1. Why does my plain text transfer fails every time, but secure socket transfers fails sometimes?
2. Why does changing the "buffer size" solves my problem?
3. If I set the "buffer size" to 10 bytes and send the data over secure socket I will receive 10 bytes at the server side. But if I send the data with the same buffer size over plain socket I receive more than 10 bytes. Is this the result of padding?
4. Is there a better way of transferring data from Android to a server via sockets?

## Client Code (Plain text)

```
protected void nonsecure_transfer(String ip, int port, int fileno) {

        Socket sock;

        try {
            sock = new Socket(ip, port);

            // sendfile
            final InputStream is;
            switch (fileno){
                case 0:
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test1mb);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test10mb);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test100mb);
                    break;
                default: is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test1mb);
                    break;
            }
            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            int buffer_size = Integer.parseInt(buffersize.getText().toString());
            byte buffer[] = new byte[buffer_size];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            os.flush();
            sock.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.append("Error \n" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.append("Error \n" + e);

        }
```

## Server Code (Plain text)

```
protected void handleConnection(Socket server) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = server.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(...);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[8129];
        int count = 0;
        int size = 0;
        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        is.close();
    }
```

## Client Code (Secure)

```
protected void secure_transfer(String ip, int port, int fileno) throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {

        String passphrase = "test123";

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream keyin = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server_keystore);
        ks.load(keyin, "test123".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);

        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        clientKeyStore.load(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client_keystore), passphrase.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(clientKeyStore, passphrase.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)
                socketFactory.createSocket(new Socket(ip, port), ip, port, false);
        socket.startHandshake();
        try {

            // sendfile
            final InputStream is;
            switch (fileno){
                case 0:
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test1mb);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test10mb);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test100mb);
                    break;
                default: is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test1mb);
                    break;
            }
            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            int buffer_size = Integer.parseInt(buffersize.getText().toString());
            byte buffer[] = new byte[buffer_size];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            os.flush();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.append("Error \n" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.append("Error \n" + e);

        }
    }
```

## Server Code (Secure)

```
public void listen() throws Exception {
        try {

            String passphrase = "test123";

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("server_keystore.jks"),"test123".toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory kmf =
                    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(ks, "test123".toCharArray());

            SSLContext sslcontext =
                    SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            ServerSocketFactory ssf =
                    sslcontext.getServerSocketFactory();


            SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)
                    ssf.createServerSocket(9999);

            while (true) {
                SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
                handleConnection(s);
                s.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("GeneralSecurityException: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    int packet = 0;
    protected void handleConnection(Socket server) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = server.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(...);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[8129];
        int count = 0;
        int size = 0;
        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        is.close();
    }
```

## OpenVPN config

```
port 1194
proto udp

dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
;client-to-client
;duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES

auth SHA256
;comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

mssfix 1500
```

## Link Info (xubuntu - openvpn)

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:19:55:dc  
          inet addr:192.168.1.216  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fdbb:8432:3a7c:0:3290:af79:3a93:dcfd/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c133:9666:4062:e40f/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fdbb:8432:3a7c::52c/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fdbb:8432:3a7c:0:f8b3:90c2:1d8f:f21e/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:162659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:63868 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:214361110 (214.3 MB)  TX bytes:18496915 (18.4 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7518 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:13666203 (13.6 MB)  TX bytes:423228 (423.2 KB)
```

## Link Info (java server)

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:26:08:e8:d3:36 
    inet 192.168.1.194 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Comment: Don't flush inside the loops.

Comment: @EJP Noted. Thank you